# Android, Modal Bottom sheet dialog, height

Tags: android, kotlin, height

I want to create modal bottom sheet dialog with the close button and give him custom height, I tried using `dismiss()`, but it's not working.

Giving this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.weget.ui.home.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.kt:41)

My code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
                    todayPromosList.adapter = homeFragmentAdapter
                    todayPromosList.layoutManager =
                        LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)

                    toursList.adapter = homeFragmentAdapter
                    toursList.layoutManager =
                        LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)

        promotionList.adapter = homeFragmentAdapter
        promotionList.layoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(context, 2)


        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(context!!)
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_search)
        bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false)

        home_search.setOnClickListener {
            bottomSheetDialog.show()
        }
        search_dialog_ic_close.setOnClickListener {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Enter your code as text, not an image. Please read `how to ask` before asking...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set a bottomSheetDialogTheme in your Activity, 
overriding the bottomSheetStyle attribute's behavior_peekHeight:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
       parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
  <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
       parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
  <item name="behavior_peekHeight">@dimen/custom_peek_height</item>
</style>
```